# If $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ are polynomials in a field such that $p(a) = q(a)$ for every $a$ in that field, can I say that they are equal?

Tags: polynomials

Let $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ be two polynomials in a field $A$. I know they are equal if $deg(p(x)) = deg(q(x))$ and all their coefficients are equal.

But, if $p(a) = q(a)$ for every $a\in A$, are they also equal?

Comment: You can consider a polynomial $ f(x)= p(x)-q(x). p(a)=q(a)$ for every a belonging to A implies $f(a)=0 $ for every a belonging to A which implies all a that belongs to A are roots of the polynomial..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is false in general, for instance in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, the polynomials $X^p -X$ and $0$ take the same values but they are not equal.

Comment: Thanks! And, with this information, I can say that, even if a polynomial $p(x)$ equals $0$ for every $x$, I cannot say that $p(x)$ is the zero polynomial, right?

Comment: Yes, indeed, but if $F$ is a field, the only polynomial in $F[X]$ that can have an infinite number of roots is the zero polynomial.